# Как в plpgsql функции сделать insert, сохранить то что тон верннет в переменной, а потом сделать еще один инсерт на основе этой переменной?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

```
create function install() returns boolean
AS $$
begin
  -- save to variable
  id = insert into pu.user (role)
  values ('admin')
  returning id;
  
  -- use id variable
  insert .... values(id);

  return true;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это можно сделать и на чистом postgres sql:

```
  with admin_user as (
    insert into users_table (role)
    values ('admin')
    returning id
  )

  insert into another_table (admin_id)
  values (admin_user.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, стоит добавить блок declare?

```sql
 create function install() returns boolean
AS $$
declare
    inserted_id integer;
begin
  -- save to variable
  inserted_id = insert into pu.user (role)
  values ('admin')
  returning id;
  
  -- use id variable
  insert .... values(inserted_id);

  return true;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```